# Writing Java Application as jar and as apk

Tags: java, android, jar, apk, portability

I am really unsure about how to use my time wisely and I really need some help at this point.

I wrote this application in java, used javafx for the GUI and I use the simple build tool in IntelliJ, which simply calls javac to compile and sets the output in a specific out folder.
It works great.

But **how** would I proceed if I want to

1. **get an actual executable, a jar, so other people can use the application?**
2. **and also deploy the application on smartphones, or only Android?**

I wrote the code so, that the GUI adapts to the actual display size of whatever the code is being run.

I am dying to hear how you guys and gals would do that.

Much love, Jiefu

Comment: To create an executable jar, you can use some build tools like Maven, Gradle.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/

Comment: JavaFX does not support Android, last I checked.

Comment: There is already experimental support for Android but currently you can only build it on Linux.

Comment: I thought, Java was supposed to be the official language for Android and run everywhere where a JRE ist.
And since AndroidStudio is basically the same as IntelliJ, I thought, there would be a relatively easyish process for this.

Answer (score 1):

Gluon mobile is the team behind the continued development of JavaFX, and yes they offer a way to deploy your javafx application to both mobile and desktop. Here is a link to their website:

https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/